# Access - return field based on criteria for a different field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I currently have a query that tells me the date of someone's last donation:

```
Max(Donations.DonationDate) AS MaxDate
```

I want to know the amount of that donation (`Donations.DonationAmount`).

I can get my query to show amounts for all donations, or I can get it to show me the amount of the maximum donation, but I don't know how to get it to show me the amount of the donation associated with MaxDate.

I'm not what terms to search for - I think I want something that will basically say "for MaxDate, return DonationAmount," but I'm not sure how to say that in SQL.

[Image of two rows of test data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFLFD.png)

If someone gave $500 on 2/2/2020 and $100 on 3/5/2020, I want to see their last donation (MaxDate). The code below correctly returns 3/5. But then I also want to see the amount of that donation on 3/5/2020 ($100).

I've figured out how to see all the amounts ($500 and $100) and how to see the maximum amount ($500), but I don't know how to figure out the value for the MaxDate's amount.

The full code:

```sql
SELECT Nz(ContactHouseholds.HouseholdName, "ACCT:" & Donations.AccountName & " CONTACT:" & Donations.ContactName) AS HsName
    ,Max(Donations.DonationDate) AS MaxDate
    ,Households.HouseholdAddressEtc
FROM (
    Donations LEFT JOIN ContactHouseholds ON Donations.ContactName = ContactHouseholds.ContactName
    )
INNER JOIN Households ON Donations.HouseholdName = Households.HouseholdName
GROUP BY Nz(ContactHouseholds.HouseholdName, "ACCT:" & Donations.AccountName & " CONTACT:" & Donations.ContactName)
    ,Households.HouseholdAddressEtc
```

Comment: Please show us sample data, expected results, and your current query.

Comment: Connect multiple queries (join or subqueries), one for MaxDate, one for Amount on that date and one for the non aggregated values (name etc)  or use [DMax](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DMin-DMax-Functions-F5C6DE87-8752-4F29-AB4B-C554053D299F) (slow).

Comment: @ComputerVersteher, could you clarify? I'm tweaking code that someone else wrote for me and am learning SQL as I go. How do I create a query for the Amount on the MaxDate?

Comment: Sample data should be text formatted as [table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]! Search for "How do I create a query for the Amount on the MaxDate"! ;(

Comment: @ComputerVersteher thank you! It turns out other people have had this exact same problem, and I was searching for it too broadly! Lesson learned.